# Arduinoのスイッチ回路図がよく分かりません

Tags: arduino

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button
このページの回路図なのですがボタン周りの回路については分かるのですがブレッドボードの右端に伸びている赤と黒のジャンプワイヤーはいったい何なのでしょうか？これなくても回路として作動しますよね。

[image: 回路図]

Answer (score 1):

テンプレートとして、電源とグランドを取り回しているだけではないでしょうか？
今後回路を足していく際に、上側の方が配線がすっきりするのでそちらから電源をとりました、でもそこはフロートで電源は引かれていませんでした。と言う単純ミスを防ぐためだと思います。